# How to set SENSOR_SENSITIVITY(Camera2) to Android CameraX

Tags: android

I want set camera sensor sensitivity (i.e. ISO) with CameraX, but cannot find any information about this. In Android Camera2, this can be done by `set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, 1600)`

What is equal function in CameraX?

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the Camera2Interop functionality of camerax

```
        ImageCapture.Builder captureBuilder = new ImageCapture.Builder();
        Camera2Interop.Extender<ImageCapture> extender = new Camera2Interop.Extender<>(captureBuilder);
        extender.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, 1600);
```